# How to start phoenixframework at host 0.0.0.0?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I tried to bind phoenix to `"0.0.0.0"` I tried in `config.exs` as:

```
config :app, App.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "0.0.0.0"],
```

And, I tried in `dev.exs` as:

```
config :app, App.Endpoint,
  http: [host: "0.0.0.0", port: 4000],
```

but neither has worked:

```
[info] Running App.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000
[warn] Transport option {:host, "0.0.0.0"} unknown or invalid.
```

So, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the `ip` key for this in `http`, with the value being a 4 element tuple of integers representing the IP. In your case, it would look like:

```
config :app, App.Endpoint,
  http: [ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}, port: 4000]
```

[Source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/591e03bc6c82b7e8a1bfdb9d239397f911026035/lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex#L7-L8)

Comment: thanks, it worked, however in the terminal log, it still says `Running App.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000`

Comment: just changing the above would result in Cowboy still using localhost, but you can change the url in the `config/config.exs` file: `config :hello, HelloWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "0.0.0.0"],`, this will result in Running HelloWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.6.1 at http://0.0.0.0.4000

Comment: Hi, I'm developing in a virtual machine with IP 192.168.100.104, when I run my program it prints `[info] Running TestWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.9.0 at 127.0.0.1:4000 (http)
[info] Access TestWeb.Endpoint at http://192.168.100.104:4000`, I can cURL 127.0.0.1:4000 from the same VM, but I cannot reach it from the host nor other machines in the same network. I must add this VM runs apache and ssh on ports 80 and 22 and I can reach both without issues.